# How to convert a linear layout to constraint layout?

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I have developed an app and I used a linear layout in every activity.Layouts of every activity look exactly the same like the one I designed in android studio when I run it on my phone (Nokia 5.1 plus). But when I run the app on another small phone like Samsung J1 layout is messed up.Some buttons,images are out of the screen.So to fix that, i mean make the layout same for every device can i use a constraint layout?

Actually i tried to convert the layout to constraint layout by right clicking on the component tree ......But after converting it doesn't look the same.Everything is messed up.

So what I want to know is,
How to make a layout looks the same in every device?

If the method is to convert it into constraint layout,how to do it without the last problem I mentioned?

Here is one of the xml codes of my activities.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".alkaned">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBack3"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="375dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView198"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/alkanesnew" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btnAlkaneM"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView401"
                android:layout_width="397dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/newfont"
                android:text="we,aflak idod.kakd wdldr "
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView209"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/milanpng" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btnAlkaneS"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView405"
                android:layout_width="397dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/newfont"
                android:text="we,aflak Ndckh jk m%;sl%shd"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView212"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/milanpng" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btnAlkaneR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView406"
                android:layout_width="397dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/newfont"
                android:text="we,aflak iïnkao mßj¾;k yd m%;sl%shd idrdxYh"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView215"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/milanpng" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library to handle your UI on different size devices.

Try using the `SDP` library. For more info & usage, you can check it out over [here](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Add this to your Gradle for using the `SDP` library.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
}
```

And in your layouts instead of `dp` use `spd` as

instead of

> android:layout_width="35dp"

use

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even on ConstraintLayout controls will be out of screen if it is so small as you said. To workaround this, you should implement for example **ScrollView** before your LinearLayout, just like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".alkaned">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBack3"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="375dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView198"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/alkanesnew" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btnAlkaneM"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView401"
                android:layout_width="397dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/newfont"
                android:text="we,aflak idod.kakd wdldr "
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView209"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/milanpng" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btnAlkaneS"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView405"
                android:layout_width="397dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/newfont"
                android:text="we,aflak Ndckh jk m%;sl%shd"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView212"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/milanpng" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/btnAlkaneR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView406"
                android:layout_width="397dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/newfont"
                android:text="we,aflak iïnkao mßj¾;k yd m%;sl%shd idrdxYh"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView215"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/milanpng" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```